# iframe in safari on ipad grabs focus on input field keydown

Tags: javascript, ipad, iframe, safari

I have a webpage which has an iframe which in turn has an input filed. if I click on the input field, ipad keyboard opens and when I keydown something, suddenly the iframe hides everything else and the webpage is just the iframe now. Iframe is clearly grabbing the focus. Even after the keyboard is closed, the view doesn't return to normal. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Note: only happening on ipads.